# Javascript function as argument

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm working on a Javascript application. I need to implement an handler which accepts a function as a parameter:

Here the example function:

```
function myfunction()
{
   alert("hello world");
}
```

and this is my handler

```
function handler(action)
{
   action();
}
```

I call the handler like this:

```
handler(myFunction);
```

it works fine on some browsers, on other doesn't work at all

what could be the problem?

Comment: which browser? as example

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: latest safari doesn't work, safari on 10.6.8 works fine

Comment: Show us the exact code you are using and the error message you get, with what you posted we cannot reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is this:

```
map = {
  myFunction : function()
       {
           alert("hello world");
       }
}

function handler(action)
{
   action();
}

handler(map.myFunction);
```

It will work in all browsers.